# How to make the level of subpackage up when import subpackge in main script?

Tags: python, relative-path

I want to make a subpackage level up to write the main script in a more simple path. That is, I want to write the path for sub2 in directly pack.sub2 rather than pack.sub1.sub2.
Now I made a directory structure and some modules as follows.

pack/sub1/sub2/mod.py

pack/**init**.py

```
from .sub1 import sub2
```

In Ipython,

```
import pack
dir(pack)
import pack.sub1
import pack.sub2
```

Error message:

```
"No module name 'pack.sub2'
```

dir(pack) shows 'sub1', 'sub2' but import pack.sub2 fails while import pack.sub1 is working naturally. In an other context such as the relation between subpackages inside a library, it might work. But in this case, it is not working. What is the working principle of python in this respect? And how to make the python main script written in a short path form importing subpackage?

Comment: I found that "from pack import sub2" is working, but "from pack.sub2 import mod" fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
pack/
|-- __init__.py
|-- sub1/
    |-- sub2/
        |-- __init__.py  
        |-- mod.py
```

I understand that this the structure. Place

```
from .sub1 import sub2
```

inside sub2's **init**.py

this will enable you to import sub2 directly from outside package using

```
import pack.sub2
```

Other way is using `sys`, but that can create thousands of other issue

Comment: Thank you for kind drawing the directory structure. And "from .sub1 import sub2" in .../sub2 is wrong. /sub2 does not have /sub1 but ../sub1.